# How to add together an array of numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to take an array of 12 numbers and add them together then call one function to get the average of the numbers and another to get the total of the numbers.

My array looks like this:

```
monthlySales[0] = 30000;
monthlySales[1] = 10000;
monthlySales[2] = 15000;
monthlySales[3] = 20000;
monthlySales[4] = 20000;
monthlySales[5] = 25000;
monthlySales[6] = 22000;
monthlySales[7] = 80000;
monthlySales[8] = 20000;
monthlySales[9] = 20000;
monthlySales[10] = 40000;
monthlySales[11] = 60000;
```

I have to use this to get the arrays values somehow:

```
lookedUpMonthlySales = chosenIndex
monthlySales[chosenIndex]
```

Im just not sure how to get the values of the arrays from the array into my other two functions and then how to add them together and to get the average of them.

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: WHAT other 2 functions?

Comment: I don't get it, are you asking how to sum the array and get an average, or something about passing the array as an argument to two other functions ?

Comment: I havent attempted anything yet cause I have no idea how arrays work. I can grab a string type array easy and return it and even just return one array but im having a problem with having to use two diffrent functions in which one sums the numbers in the array and the other gets the average of the numbers in the array. The functions are calculateAnnual and calculateAverage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment request...  This illustrates exactly what is asked for in the question.
A function to add the elements up.  And a function to get the average.  This is assuming that the provided array is populated as the question states.

```
   function addUp(monthlySales) {
      var xx, totalOfArray;
      for (xx = 0; xx < 12; xx++) {
          totalOfArray = totalOfArray + monthlySales[xx];
      }
      return totalOfArray;
   }

   function averageOf(totalIs,elems) {
       var averageOfArray = totalIs/elems;
       return averageOfArray;
   }

//To find the sum of the elements in the array:
var totalIs = addUp(monthlySales);
//To find the average:
var averageIs = averageOf(totalIs,12);
alert(averageIs);
```

Comment: please add some explanation of your code and how it solves the problem to help others

Comment: I just added `var` statements to your code. It is very important to declare your variables in JS, otherwise they will be implicit globals and possibly cause all sorts of bugs. Also, it is a [convention in JS](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) to only capitalize variables that are the names of [constructor functions](http://helephant.com/2008/09/14/constructor-functions/).

Answer (score 3):

To sum:

```
monthlySales.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
});
```

To calculate the average:

```
monthlySales.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
}) / monthlySales.length;
```

You can read more about `reduce` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through array and send them to your function, and AVG you can find by making sum of all elements and I will show you how

```
var _sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < monthlySales[0].length; i++)
{
 _sum += monthlySales[0];
}
var avg = _sum/monthlySales.length;
```